# How to loop/process Javascript Key:Value pairs?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the following code:

```
a = {};
a['a'] = 1;
a['b'] = 3;
a['c'] = 5;
a['d'] = 2;

b = [];
b['a'] = 1;
b['b'] = 3;
b['c'] = 5;
b['d'] = 2;

console.log(typeof a, typeof b);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

And the output `console.log` is as follow:

```
object object
{ a: 1, b: 3, c: 5, d: 2 }
[ a: 1, b: 3, c: 5, d: 2 ]
```

Granted that they are of both type `object`, to my understanding, `a` is an object of `key:value` pairs, where as `b` is an array of `[key:value]` pairs. Is that the right assumption?

And aside from a `for(index in array)` pattern of looping, where I have to use the iterator index to grab the value (`array[index]`), is there a better, more simple method of looping through these key/value pairs to grab the index/value or to just process the data at each index, sort of like `map` or `reduce` for arrays?

One such problem I ran into was, if I wanted to grab the key with the least count (in the above examples, it would be 'a'), is there a way to do it without using the `for( index in array)` pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript arrays are objects, so you *can* add keys like you are doing in your example above, but this is not the normal way to use arrays and will probably confuse a lot of people looking at your code. There are occasional when it's useful to add a property to an array, but using them just as key stores definitely not the norm.

If you want an *ordered* collections with numeric indexes, use an array:

```js
let arr = []
arr.push(10)
arr.push(20)
console.log(arr)
console.log(arr[0])
```

If you want properties where order isn't important and you will have string keys, use an object. In the above example you are using both types like objects  — there's no reason to use an array like that.

Having said that if you want an iterator of values from an object, you can use `Object.values()`. This delivers an array of values from an object if you only want to process the values:

```js
a = {};
a['a'] = 1;
a['b'] = 3;
a['c'] = 5;
a['d'] = 2;

console.log(Object.values(a))

// process them
let newArr = Object.values(a).map(n => n * 10)
console.log(newArr)
```

`Object.entries` is also useful — it returns an array of key/value pairs, which, with `reduce()` makes a nice way to find the minimum:

```js
a = {
  a: 1,
  b: 3,
  c: 5,
  d: 2
};

// current will be an array of the form [key, value]
let [minKey, minValue] = Object.entries(a).reduce((min, current) => min[1] < current[1] ? min : current)
console.log(minKey, minValue)
```